# Change previewMaxWidth/Height of jQuery File Upload (blueimp) programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, blueimp

I am implementing the Blueimp jQuery File Uploader https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload and I'm wanting to change the **previewMaxWidth** and **previewMaxHeight** after the first image is added. This is because I have a product feature image and then subsequent views of the product, each of which should display smaller than the feature image.

Here is my file upload call:

```
$('.imageupload').fileupload({
    autoUpload : true,
    acceptFileTypes : /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
    previewMaxWidth : 198,
    previewMaxHeight : 800,
    uploadTemplateId : 'product-add-image-upload',
    downloadTemplateId : 'product-add-image-download'
}).bind('fileuploadadded', function(e, data) {
    // change preview width/height to 60px/60px after first image loaded
    // not sure what to put here

});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is present `option` param that allows to change *options* after widget is initialized.

According to your code:

```
...

}).bind('fileuploadadded', function(e, data) {
    $('.imageupload').fileupload(
        'option',
        {
            previewMaxWidth: 60,
            previewMaxHeight: 60
        }
    );
});
```

More info about changing options see at official [API](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API) page (section *Options*).

Comment: Ugh, I can't believe I didn't see that. Thanks. It works perfectly!